# noun phrase '' and ''?

Tags: grammar

***Between the hotel and the market where my house is located...***

***Mary and her dog, that I love very much...***

I know that the relative clause modifies noun or noun phrases. Well, in these sentences, do we include "and" and "between" in the noun phrase?

Is "that" just a replacement for "her dog" or what?

Because there is also the fact that a relative clause or relative pronoun usually replaces and modifies the word closest to it.

I would be very grateful if you could enlighten me on this issue.

Comment: Between" is a preposition here, so your first example is a preposition phrase with a coordination of the two NPs "the hotel" and "the market" as its complement. “And” is considered to be part of the second NP.  Your second example also consists of a coordination of two noun phrase, "Mary" and "her dog". Again, the coordinator "and" is considered to be part of the second coordinate. "That" is a subordinator, not a relative pronoun. It doesn't replace anything, but simply introduces the relative clause.

Comment: real linguists don't recognize it as a relative pronoun, as you say. but in traditional grammar books it is a relative pronoun. for example : Raymond Murphy : English Grammar in use. Unit 93. The woman who lives next door is a doctor or (or The woman that lives .. . ) Where is the cheese that was in the fridge? (or the cheese which was ... ) He said. Thank you.

Comment: Is the house located on the market place, or between the hotel and the market?

Comment: Incidentally, _that_ relatives are always defining, but the comma in your example marks it as non-defining. You need to replace "that" with "who(m)".

Comment: It's possible for a relative clause to modify the second, both, or even in some contexts the first of a pair of connected phrases. With a good writer, it's obvious from context, or maybe doesn't matter. There's also a clue in the second example with "that", which is used with a dog but not normally a named person ("Mary, who...").